# Differencess in process tree after stop session for few mins

Tags: linux, process, sleep

> Stop executing session for 3 mins with the `sleep` command and show differences in the process tree (with `+` symbol for new processes and `-` symbol for those which are gone).

How to write a script for this exercise?

Comment: Do you expect from us to do your homework?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

ps aux >ps-out.old
sleep 180
ps aux >ps-out.new

diff -u ps-out.old ps-out.new | grep '^[+-]'
```

This executes `ps aux` and saves the result to a file.  Then it waits for three minutes before doing the same again.  Then it uses `diff` to get the differences between the two sets of output from `ps`, and `grep` to only get the lines in the `diff` output that has been added or removed.